# How to export annotations from mobi/epub files?

Tags: ebook-reader

So I use FBreader for mobi/epub ebooks and I highlight lots of text.

How can I export all the highlights I've made into another file (or share them all with the Internet)?

Answer (score 2):

OK, this might not be really relevant to this post, but for other FBReader users who are stuck at the same, I'll share my (rough) solution:

Note: This should be specially relevant to Icarus eReader users! Icarus e-ink readers come with a modified version of FBReader 2 which is pretty stable on that device but unfortunately very basic too. And you can't even update it! I don't know if newer versions of FBReader can do this by default - sorry if this is obsolete information to most of you.

1. Using a file manager with root access on your ereader (I use [Solid Explorer](http://neatbytes.com/solidexplorer/)) , navigate to `/data/data/org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/databases/`
2. Select the `books.db` file and copy it to a non-root directory (like for example to `/sdcard/`) that you can later access from your computer.
3. On your computer, open `books.db` with [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) (you can't just open a .db file with a text editor, you'll see unreadable code). I guess you can perform this step directly on Android with Sqlite Viewer for Android, but I haven't tried that yet.
4. In SQLiteBrowser, go to the `Annotations` table of your database and you'll see all your highlights. SQLB is not the best app for editing text, but there's a few export options.

There you go!

Comment: To access that dir, Sqlite Viewer (see Settings) requires FuseDroid , which itself requires SuperUser or SuperSU, which require a rooted device. But Sqlite Viewer says "this app does not support rooted device"

Answer (score 1):

http://ebookfriendly.com/evernote-tips-for-booklovers/

Check Tip #3, exporting through email to evernote with an IFTTT recipe (man, those are cool).

IDK if this works for FBreader, but its worth a shot. Should work for Moon+, most people online seem to be recommending that app for exporting notes.

I'm having so much trouble with this kind of problem. Don't trust when Play Books says it will export your highlights/notes to your Google Drive (a new feature) - I haven't gotten it to work once!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings in FB Reader on your device.  Set it to synchronize.  Go to https://books.fbreader.org/.  View the book.  Click on bookmarks.  You can export them as text.